# Is sforzando on two beats sensible? Are there alternatives?

Tags: piano, notation, accent

For a piano piece, I want a sforzando (which I interpret as a strong accent on every note in that beat) to be applied to two beats. Until now I have notated it like this, with sffz between the notes:

[image: example 1]

I think this is understandable, if admittedly non-standard. However this becomes less elegant to write when the division between those notes falls on the border of a bar:

[image: example 2]

I'm unsure as to workable alternatives. Writing *subito ff* and *subito mf* afterwards feels overwritten. Just replacing it with > accent marks seems somehow weaker, and it would require three marks on the left-hand notes (which should be staccato like the others, and I gave them marcato too because I wish the bass to be slightly dominant).

EDIT: two sforzandos after each other also works, though it looks a bit busy.

[image: example 3]

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just place two *sffz*s?

Comment: @Aaron Fair point, I suppose I could, but I don't think I have seen two of those in a row before. I thought that they implied immediate decrease in volume right afterwards, like *fp*?

Comment: There’s not much difference between sfz and an accent mark, right?

Comment: @ToddWilcox In my understanding sfz is stronger, sffz even more so, plus the mark applies to the whole beat, regardless of voices or (in the case of piano) staves.

Comment: @KeizerHarm - Wait, sfz and sffz applied to the whole beat? In my experience, both of them apply to *that note only*, and I swear I've seen multiple sfz's in a row.

Comment: @Dekkadeci To be sure I'm not miscommunicating, let me clarify that by "applies to beat" I mean "every note hit in that exact moment in time". Basically I mean that in piano score the sffz in the middle applies to left and right hand both, like dynamic marks do.

Comment: @KeizerHarm - Given your "Until now I have notated it like this, with sffz between the notes", I thought that, by "applies to the whole beat", you meant "applies to the entire length of one beat as defined by the time signature". By "that note only", I did mean all notes played in that exact moment of time by that instrument (this means grace notes don't get affected by the sfz).

Comment: @Dekkadeci Good to have cleared that up :) I understand that sffz between notes is non-standard and I did not mean to imply that that was regular, it was just a stopgap measure for want of a better alternative. Now it looks like there isn't one except two sffz's in a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How to mark the passages

*Sforzando* and related markings apply only to individual notes, so the single ***sffz*** on two adjacent notes within the same measure is technically incorrect, and I personally would find it confusing. Consider a *sub **ff*** followed by a separate marking to return to the prevailing dynamic. That would be unambiguous, especially with the other articulation marks present.

Where the two notes are in separate measures, two ***sffz*** markings will be aesthetically fine and clear to read; however, for clarity use the same markings in both parts of the score. That is, if you use ***sffz*** in one place, use it in both; likewise with *sub **ff***; but use one or the other, not both.

#### Duration of *sforzando* and related markings

Regarding the ***sffz*** applying to a full beat — this is not a rule or guideline I've encountered, nor can I find evidence to suggest that interpretation. Here is what Wikipedia [has to say](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamics_(music)#Changes) on the subject:

> *Subito* can be used to mark suddenly louder changes, like *subito forte* ***sf***, or *subito fortissimo* ***sff***, however in these cases it's usually only used to add a particular amount of accent to one note or chord. If subito is used to note a sudden change to an entire louder passage, something like *sub. **f*** or *sub. **ff*** should be used to leave out any ambiguity.

> Forzando/forzato indicates a forceful accent and is abbreviated as ***fz***. To emphasize the effect, it is most often preceded with *subito* as ***sfz*** (*subito forzato/forzando*, *sforzando/sforzato*). How these should be interpreted and played in the music is up to the judgement of the performer, but a rule of thumb is that a *forzato/forzando* can be considered as a variation on *marcato* while *subito forzando/forzato* can be considered a variation on *marcato* with added *tenuto*.

The Oxford Online Music Dictionary [doesn't comment on the duration](https://doi.org/10.1093/gmo/9781561592630.article.25552) of a *sfortissimo*, but Dolmetsch backs up the [single-note/chord idea](https://www.dolmetsch.com/defss2.htm).

> ***sf.***: abbreviation for *sforzato*, applied to a single accented note

Dolmetsch entries for related terms aren't specific about duration, but the above seems to be the ruling entry.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. The duration part is entirely new to me, and I had indeed always assumed that it applied to a beat (per instrument) rather than a note/chord, just like any dynamic letter mark (*pp, mf*, etc
). Weirdly, the first example of *sf* in piano music I came across (Pictures at an Exhibition 9. Baba Yaga) actually uses *sf* in both ways.

Answer (score 2):

If you want sffz on two notes, I'm afraid you have to write it twice.

Some would say sffz and a staccato dot were contradictory.

An alternative might be ff with an accent and tenuto line on each note.